# Copy specific cell to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I over my head on this one.
I want to copy cell G4 & I4 (main Sheet) to cell C7 & H7 of another sheet (Last available row). The problem that I have is the sheet that the data needs to be pasted to is named after the value of Cell R4 in the main sheet.  The data is only copy if the value of Main sheet Cell Q4 is true (set thru active x control)
Thanks for your help

Comment: `cell C7 & H7` or `Last Available Row`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
Sub main()
Dim intCountRows As Integer
If Range("Q4") = True Then
    intCountRows = GetCount(3, Worksheets(Range("R4")))
    Worksheets(Range("R4")).Cells(intCountRows, 3) = Range("G4")
    intCountRows = GetCount(8, Worksheets(Range("R4")))
    Worksheets(Range("R4")).Cells(intCountRows, 8) = Range("I4")
End If
End Sub

Function GetCount(ByVal intColumn As Integer, ByRef wrkSheet As Worksheet) As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim flag As Boolean
i = 1
flag = True
While flag = True
    If wrkSheet.Cells(i, intColumn) <> "" Then
        i = i + 1
    Else
        flag = False
    End If
Wend

GetCount = i - 1
End Function
```

Also i have written an article about [working with worksheets](http://software-solutions-online.com/2014/02/26/excel-vba-working-with-sheets/) in my blog

Comment: Thanks for that but how can I make sure that the paste data is on the last aval row?